# kendo ui requestEnd event fires only once. Why?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete, kendo-datasource

i have a kendo grid whose detail rows are populated with editable grids of popup creation mode. Inside each of those popup creation windows i use, among others, a kendo autocomplete widget:

```
                    $("#labResponsibleRegistryNo").kendoAutoComplete({
                        dataSource: labResponsiblesDS,
                        dataTextField: "fullname",                            
                        template: "<div class='labResponsiblesTemplate'>\
                                        <span class='template_fullname'> #= lastname + ' ' + firstname #</span>\
                                        <div class='template_details'>\
                                            <span> ΑΜ </span>\
                                            <span class='template_data'> #= registry_no # </span>\
                                        </div>\
                                    <div>",
                        minLength: 3
                        //suggest: true,
                    });
```

which i bind with the labResponsiblesDS datasource, below:

```
        var labResponsiblesDS=  new kendo.data.DataSource({
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "api/workers",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {},
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                parameterMap: function(data, type) {
                    if (type === 'read') {
                        data["worker"] = data.filter.filters[0].value;
                        delete data.filter;
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "data",
                total: "total"
            },
            requestEnd: function(e) {
                console.log("labResponsiblesDS requestEnd", e);
                if(e.response.data.length > 0){
                    var results_no = e.response.data.length;
                    for(var i=0;i<results_no;i++){
                        e.response.data[i].fullname = e.response.data[i].lastname + " " + e.response.data[i].firstname;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

In labResponsiblesDS 's request End event, I create in each one of the results returned from the server, an extra field "fullname" which is the concatenation of two of the fields returned "lastname" and "firstname". "fullname" is used in the autocomplete's dataTextField.

My problem is that after achieving the autocomplete widget's desirable functionality inside some nested grid's popup create window, when i close that popup and reopen it or open another nested grid's popup, the requestEnd event FAILS to fire. Any advice would be much appreciated.THanks in advance

Comment: I guess it only hit once or initially cause you read data initially for the first page. As server filtering sets to "true" if you hit the pagination button it should get another hit. 

am I getting right?? you have a grid and you are using a kendo autocomplete in the grid.. which is in popup editing.. not inline.. in that why don't you use "editor" option in the column declaration??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the fullname value directly into your schema.  You would just need to implement the schema.data as an anonymous function, and form the fullname there:

```
schema: {
    data: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            data[i].fullname = data[i].lastname + " " + data[i].firstname;
        }
        return data;
    },
    total: "total"
}
```